# .append to create sortable table from within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sorttable.js

I have a list of options with different values. I listen to the events of my list using:

`value = $('#list option:select').val();`

I then perform different actions based on the value like so

```
if (value == 'a') {
$('table').contents(); //clear content
$('table').append(
'<table class="sortable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="">Name</th>
   <th class="">Unit1</th>
   <th class="">Unit2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Fitz, Marvin</td>
  <td>$3300</td>
  <td>5554</td>
 </tr>'); //add content

} else if (value == "b" {

$('table').contents(); //clear content
$('table').append(<new table>);
```

To do this I'm following: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ using the sorttable.js as script source.

The table updates perfectly but doesn't seem to be effected by the sorttable.js. Given the .append happends within a function (or for any other reason), do I have to approach this differently than normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reInit sorttable with following after data append to table:

```
sorttable.makeSortable($("table.sortable"));
```

For More detail : http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#ajaxtables

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a subtle issue to do with when the table is made sortable by the sorttable library. From looking at the source, I think adding `sorttable.init()` after you append your new table should fix this.